# Elegant way to convert collection to be mutable before removing element?

Tags: java

For defensive programming purpose, whenever need to remove elements from collections, I have to convert it to mutable collection just in case.

```
public void removeNull(List<String> strList){
    strList = new ArrayList<String>(strList);
    strList.removeIf(Objects::isNull);
}
```

Any API like common library to combine above 2 lines to have a safe way to ensure a mutable collection to remove element?

Comment: This code effectively does nothing.

Comment: If a collection is not mutable, you cannot remove elements from it, period. Creating an `ArrayList` and then removing elements from it would remove elements from the `ArrayList`, not the original collection. What's the point of all this?

Comment: You wont be able to change the original list by just reassigning it like that. See [Java pass-by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/16034206)

Comment: Shouldn't you be wondering why there are null elements in your list in the first place? I mean, if you need to clean them, maybe they shouldn't get there at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your above example does nothing because [Java is always pass-by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/16034206). For true defensive programming, you should return a new List instead. E.g. by streaming (Note that the returned list is unmodifiable)

```java
public List<String> removeNull(List<String> strList){
    return strList.stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .toList();
}
```

and further down the line, you can assign the returned value to it.

```java
final var listWithoutNulls = removeNull(listWithMaybeNulls);
```

Comment: Your solution will only filter the null elements, I think you forgot a not in the filter condition